# Problem with accessing value from .JSON (path issue probably)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a react component that uses api data:

```
class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: {}
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3005/products/157963')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state.output);
    const { general = {name:""} } = this.state.output;
    const { id } = this.state.output;
    const { images = {large:""} } = this.state.output;
  return (
    <ItemPanel>
    <ItemBox>
    <BoxTitle>{general.name}</BoxTitle>
    <BoxId>Item ID: {id}</BoxId>
    <Details onClick={show_details}>Show more...</Details>
        <Inline>
        <Quantity type="number" defaultValue="1"></Quantity>
        <Icon>add_shopping_cart</Icon>
        </Inline>
        <AddItem>
        <Sfont>Add to cart</Sfont>
    </AddItem>
    </ItemBox>
        <BoxImg src={images} alt='img error'></BoxImg>
</ItemPanel>
  );
}
}
export default Item;
```

and this is what .JSON look like:

```
{
"id": "774944",
"general": {
  "presentable_id": "774944",
  "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
  "description": ""
},
"brand": {
  "name": "Brother Norge AS"
},
"images": {
  "primary": {
    "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
  }
}
}
```

I need to access the image src link from "large" in 'images/primary'.
Have tried many variations here, but it always returns as empty or undefined object :/

Comment: use `this.state.output.images.primary.large`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const {images:{primary:{large}}} = this.state.output;
console.log(large)
```

you'll have the image path in large variable.

Comment: Thanks! It needs to be first declared as empty:  const {images = {primary:{large:""}}} = this.state.output;  ,but its working fine now.